# apple remote control setup on iMac with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, remote, apple, lirc

in the process of setting up the remote control of my iMac (running Ubuntu 12.10), I am stuck.

I followed the instructions that I found on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LIRC and I am stuck after the irw part: as advised in the how-to, I run

```
irw
```

and I correctly see the signal the remote is sending (play, pause, forward etc.). Sofar everything perfect.

Then I got a .lircrc from the web containing this:

```
##################################################
#### Save as ~/.lircrc ###########################
#### After modifying: ############################
#### sudo /etc/init.d/lirc restart ###############
##################################################

#############
#### VLC ####
#############

begin
prog = vlc
button = KEY_PLAYPAUSE
config = key-play-pause
repeat = 0
end

begin
prog = vlc
button = KEY_MENU
config = key-stop
repeat = 0
end

begin
prog = vlc
button = KEY_REWIND
config = key-jump-short
repeat = 1
end

begin
prog = vlc
button = KEY_FORWARD
config = key-jump+short
repeat = 1
end

begin
prog = vlc
button = KEY_VOLUMEUP
config = key-vol-up
repeat = 1
end

begin
prog = vlc
button = KEY_VOLUMEDOWN
config = key-vol-down
repeat = 1
end

#################
#### MPlayer ####
#################

#begin mplayer
begin
prog = mplayer
button = KEY_PLAYPAUSE
config = pause
repeat = 15
end

begin
prog = mplayer
button = KEY_MENU
config = stop
repeat = 15
end

begin
prog = mplayer
button = KEY_REWIND
config = seek -10
repeat = 10
end

begin
prog = mplayer
button = KEY_FORWARD
config = seek +10
repeat = 10
end

begin
prog = mplayer
button = KEY_VOLUMEUP
config = volume 1
repeat = 1
end

begin
prog = mplayer
button = KEY_VOLUMEDOWN
config = volume -1
repeat = 1
end
#end mplayer

###############
#### Totem ####
###############

begin
prog = Totem
button = KEY_PLAYPAUSE
config = play_pause
end

begin
prog = Totem
button = KEY_MENU
config = fullscreen
end

begin
prog = Totem
button = KEY_FORWARD
config = seek_forward
end

begin
prog = Totem
button = KEY_REWIND
config = seek_backward
end

begin
prog = Totem
button = KEY_VOLUMEUP
config = volume_up
repeat = 1
end

begin
prog = Totem
button = KEY_VOLUMEDOWN
config = volume_down
repeat = 1
end

###################
#### Audacious ####
###################

begin
prog = audacious
button = KEY_PLAYPAUSE
config = PAUSE
repeat = 16
end

begin
prog = audacious
button = KEY_MENU
config = STOP
repeat = 0
end

begin
prog = audacious
button = KEY_FORWARD
config = NEXT
repeat = 16
end

begin
prog = audacious
button = KEY_REWIND
config = PREV
repeat = 16
end

################################################## ##############################
#### Turn up and down the volume (Working by default on Feisty) ####
################################################## ##############################

begin
prog = irexec
button = KEY_VOLUMEUP
config = amixer set PCM 9+ & #amixer set PCM 3%+ &
repeat = 2
end

begin
prog = irexec
button = KEY_VOLUMEDOWN
config = amixer set PCM 9- & #amixer set PCM 3%- &
repeat = 2
end

##############################################
#### Evince y OpenOffice (Presentations) ####
#### start with line command:
#### $ irxevent -d
#### and kill with:
#### $ killall irxevent
##############################################

begin
prog = irxevent
button = KEY_PLAYPAUSE
config = Key F11 CurrentWindow
config = Key F5 CurrentWindow
repeat = 0
end

begin
prog = irxevent
button = KEY_MENU
config = Key Escape CurrentWindow
repeat = 0
end

begin
prog = irxevent
button = KEY_REWIND
config = Key Prior CurrentWindow
repeat = 1
end

begin
prog = irxevent
button = KEY_FORWARD
config = Key Next CurrentWindow
repeat = 1
end

begin
prog = irxevent
button = KEY_VOLUMEUP
config = Key ctrl-plus CurrentWindow
repeat = 0
end

begin
prog = irxevent
button = KEY_VOLUMEDOWN
config = Key ctrl-minus CurrentWindow
repeat = 0
end
```

which I chose because it was looking as it should according to the lirc page ( http://www.lirc.org/html/configure.html#lircrc_format )

Then I thought that this would be it so I ran

```
irexec -d
```

thinking that I could then be able to play/pause/forward my favorite videos on vlc with the remote control, but after firing vlc it wasn't working.

I rebooted, retried, tried also other times by running the deamon (as root or not, trying actually every combination) with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lirc start
```

but no success. I searched and couldn't found something working. I may missed something. Obviously I did something wrong (or forgot to do something), therefore I would like to ask you guys your help/advice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the lirc interface of vlc player in order for this to work.